# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Portuguese Language has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: stafusa]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5939644010070016).

Comment: Thank you very much for letting PSE hold this election, I think it can be an important step towards the growth of the site.

Comment: Muitos parabéns pela eleição @stafusa!

Answer (score 7):

Meu muitíssimo obrigado a todos!

- Obrigado por terem votado! Mais da metade dos eleitores que visitaram a página participaram.
- Obrigado ao gmauch por viabilizar essa eleição com sua ótima candidatura.
- E obrigado por me elegerem — seu voto de confiança significa muito para mim.

Comment: Obrigado também ao bad_coder por sua participação estimulante durante a nominação.

Answer (score 4):

Parabéns ao @stafusa e reconhecimento ao @gmauch por nos terem dado a oportunidade de escolhermos entre eles.

Passada a eleição fica esta palavra de aviso, as coisas na rede SE nem sempre são o que parece. Compreender bem como trabalha o site e os riscos que a sua utilização envolve demora tempo. Assim como ser um bom moderador é um processo de aprendizagem.

Desejo felicidades ao @stafusa nas suas novas funções, por voluntariamente meter-se nesta alhada. (É tradição falar mal dos políticos, esperemos ter sorte com o que nos calhou.)

Comment: E quais “riscos” seriam esses? A minha curiosidade não poderia deixar isso passar. :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe podes começar por pesquisar na [tag privacidade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy). Há lá utilizadores e moderadores experientes a levantar preocupações válidas que ficaram anos por resolver.

Comment: Obrigado! E bota aprender nisso. Gastei umas boas horas nesses últimos dias lendo o material disponível para (novos) moderadores, e estou longe de terminar.

Answer (score 4):

Parabéns ao @stafusa! Principalmente por ter-se exposto como 1º candidato e tornar realidade esta 1ª eleição *pró-tempore*. Espero que a comunidade tenha valorizado esta eleição, que, espero, seja a 1ª de muitas.

Tenho certeza que farás um grande *mod term*. De fato, ao ver nossos nomes nas eleições e fazendo uma análise objetiva do *candidate score*, *reputation* e *badges* quase votei em ti!

Obrigado pelo comprometimento com esta comunidade e no que for possível ajudar, é só avisar!

Comment: Muito obrigado por tudo. Você é diretamente responsável pelo sucesso dessa eleição.

Answer (score 4):

Parabéns ao @stafusa! Eu o conheço pessoalmente (é meu primo) e embora eu seja muito enviesado, garanto a todos que ele é muito inteligente, esperto, extremamente equilibrado e sensato. É alguém que é muito difícil de se irritar e nunca o vi agir por impulso, por raiva e nem de forma desidiosa. É também bastante ativo aqui e conhece bem o funcionamento da SE.

Assim sendo, definitivamente ele é alguém muito preparado para ser um dos nossos moderadores. O PT.SE está em boas mãos!

Comment: > "muito difícil de se irritar" — Infelizmente não é bem assim. :-D O que é fundamental é tirar um tempo para se centrar antes de reagir.